# Get Eloquent model based on the precense of a value in json type column

Tags: json, laravel, database, eloquent

I want filter product by gender(men,women)

gender of the product saved in database within json format like `["\u0622\u0642\u0627\u06cc\u0627\u0646"]`

in my controller want get product by gender name

```php
    public function index(){     
        $product = Product::where(['gender' => json_decode('men',true)])
            ->orderBy('created_at','Desc')->get();
}
```

how can fetch product that gender is men or women
Some products can be used for both men and women, so I save in Json format

dd from product as you can see gender store in json format:

[image: dd from product as you can see gender store in json format]

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: $product = Product::where(['gender' => json_decode('men',true)])
       ->orWhere(['gender' => json_decode('women',true)])
        ->orderBy('created_at','Desc')->
        get();
Try this one

Comment: not working i wrote this code

Comment: can you dd(Product::all()) ;? and add output

Comment: are you store the values in arabic language in your db?

Comment: store value in my database is persian(Farsi) language

Comment: men = مردانه
women= زنانه

Comment: gender is a string column is not?

Comment: no its not string

Comment: its json format

Comment: `json_decode('men',true)` is going to return null because that is not valid JSON. Why are you using JSON at all? Just store a number. 0=unisex, 1=male, 2=female. Words like "مردانه" are about presentation, this is nothing to do with storage.

Answer (score -1):

## Searching values in Json

### Mysql

Actually having **json data** for a column, make it hard for indexing and searching in RDBMS databases like Mariadb, mysql, ....

### Key-value No-Sql DBMS

if you use mongo, cockroach, DynoDB, ... they are embracing this approach.
but you would need to redesign all the DB architecture !!!

### Postgres

but if you are using **Postgres DB** it would be fine as long as you use the `Jsonb` data type for the *gender* column.

but as i can see your foreign keys as `1,2,3 ...`, I assume that you are using mysql maybe.

## Redesign DB Schema instead of migrating to Postgres

I would like to recommend to use **boolean** or **enum** type column which more suites your scenario, instead of Json.

- with **boolean** columns you can have **multiple selected attributes** for given data.
  like : either "Mardaneh" & "Zananeh" & "Bacheganeh" ...
- with the **enum** you would be sure at DB level that, **there is a gender has been selected**

in your case I guess two boolean column makes more sense.